# NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions (Android Push Development)

Tags: java, android, build, push, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to run a [sample project for doing Android Push notifications with Urban Airship](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started:+Android:+C2DM+Push). My program can't seem to find this `AirshipConfigOptions` class. The project builds fine, only throws this error at runtime.

Here is what my project structure looks like:

[image]

Here is the error I'm getting:

> 05-09 18:50:10.926: I/dalvikvm(2007): Could not find method com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions, referenced from method com.urbanairship.push.sample.MyApplication.onCreate
>   05-09 18:50:10.946: I/dalvikvm(2007): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   05-09 18:50:11.016: W/dalvikvm(2007): VFY: unable to resolve static method 46: Lcom/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions;.loadDefaultOptions (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions;
>   05-09 18:50:11.016: D/dalvikvm(2007): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
>   05-09 18:50:11.115: D/dalvikvm(2007): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x004a at 0x0f in Lcom/urbanairship/push/sample/MyApplication;.onCreate
>   05-09 18:50:11.115: D/AndroidRuntime(2007): Shutting down VM
>   05-09 18:50:11.115: W/dalvikvm(2007): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007): **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions**
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at com.urbanairship.push.sample.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:46)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   05-09 18:50:11.125: E/AndroidRuntime(2007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-09 18:50:11.215: E/dalvikvm(2007): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Is a directory
>   05-09 18:50:11.486: I/dalvikvm(2007): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   05-09 18:50:11.526: I/dalvikvm(2007): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   05-09 18:50:11.795: I/dalvikvm(2007): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   05-09 18:50:11.815: I/dalvikvm(2007): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Also, I am already aware that I need to put JARs in a "libs" folder, not a "lib" folder, as [documented here](http://www.wiseappsllc.com/homepage/android-dev-tips).

---

Update 1:

I have the following activities in my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
        <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.push.sample.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.push.sample.PushPreferencesActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.push.sample.LocationActivity" />
```

Here is a screenshot of my Java Build Path:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you declared everything in your android manifest file?  You can't just add libraries and activities to src and then run the things,  you have to add every new activity to the manifest as well.

From the looks of the stack trace it seems you are missing activities for airship.

You should also check your build properties and make extra sure that your airship jar is in the build order.

Comment: @Ed Duderino, thanks for the comment. I just updated my post to include the build path and activities that I have in my project. So it's unclear if that's the problem. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok this is certainly a problem with your build.  Sometimes eclipse is particularly difficult to work with when importing a project.  I reviewed the instructions at the link you provided originally and if I were you I would wipe your location, re-create the project and follow the instructions closely, they look solid.  Sometimes you have to add the right versions of java and the android libraries to the project when you import also.  Pay particular attention to the instructions for the manifest regarding the service and receiver declarations also.